# Android app crashing after clicking a button

Tags: android, debugging, crash

Im trying to make an app for android. And after some testing on my own device i thought well on my phone and the emulator's it works pretty good.

but now the weird stuff begins! I made an debug APK to send to a friend of mine so he could install it and test it. But at this specific button click the app crashes. We thought maybe its the phone and did another test with 2 other phones(all diffrent models or brands). And the same thing happends.

The we thought lets try to install the app on my friends phone with Android Studio(the same as my initial test) and at that point the app workt prefect on his cellphone.

So i made another APK and tested it on some phones hoping it would work. But no, it still crashes after the install from the debug/release APK.

Here i have the code which is fired after the button click.

```
 stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (stopButton.getText().equals("Next")) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(Timer.this, MyActivity.class);

                Timer.this.startActivity(startIntent);
            } else if (stopButton.getText().equals("Show income")) {


                //
                HashMap<String, String> shitList = dbTool.getWageInfo();


                if (shitList.get("type").equals("0")) {
                    stringWageHour = shitList.get("hourWage");
                    amountPayed = Double.parseDouble(stringWageHour);
                    setAmountPayed(amountPayed);
                } else {
                    stringHours = shitList.get("hourMonth");
                    stringMonthPay = shitList.get("wageMonth");
                    doubleHours = Double.parseDouble(stringHours);
                    doubleMonthPay = Double.parseDouble(stringMonthPay);
                    calculateHours = doubleMonthPay / doubleHours;
                    setAmountPayed(calculateHours);
                }


                getText = textTimer.getText().toString();

                amountMinuts = Double.parseDouble(getText);
                minutWage = amountMinuts / 60;
                FinalAmount = amountPayed * minutWage;
                formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                output = formatter.format(FinalAmount);

                finalAmountString = String.valueOf(output);
                textTimer.setText(finalAmountString);

                HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                queryValuesMap.put("time", getText);
                queryValuesMap.put("earned", finalAmountString);

                dbTool.insertShit(queryValuesMap);


                stopButton.setText("Next");
            } else {
                timeSwap += timeInMillies;
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);

                string = textTimer.getText().toString();
                tmp = string.split(":");
                amountSeconds = Double.parseDouble(tmp[1]);

                amountMinuts = Double.parseDouble(tmp[0]);


                minutsSec = amountSeconds / 60;
                formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                output = formatter.format(minutsSec);

                minutsSecFinal = Double.parseDouble(output);
                minuts = minutsSecFinal + amountMinuts;

                Final = String.valueOf(minuts);
                textTimer.setText(Final);

                stopButton.setText("Show income");
            }
        }
    });

}

private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

        seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

The button fails when the text is "stop" and would use the else statement.
Because i can't recreate the problem when normally debuggig i dont have an log(if someone has an idea to create one i would also be of help)

EDIT:
the error code from google play dev:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "0,12"
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
at jmsbrk.crappapp.Timer$1.onClick(Timer.java:190)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5088)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The wage info"

```
public HashMap<String,String> getWageInfo(){
    HashMap<String,String> wageMap = new  HashMap<String,String>();

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM wage ";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{


            wageMap.put("wageId",cursor.getString(0));
            wageMap.put("type",cursor.getString(1));
            wageMap.put("hourWage",cursor.getString(2));
            wageMap.put("wageMonth",cursor.getString(3));
            wageMap.put("hourMonth",cursor.getString(4));


        }while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return  wageMap;
}
```

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey added getWageInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the Same Function On for the Every Button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainlayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainlayout1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:onClick="CallMe"
        android:background="@drawable/btnround"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Call the function and do it like this

public void ClickMe(View view)
{

```
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.stopbutton:
                //dosomething
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
```

}

Comment: @user3930864 amountPayed = Double.parseDouble(stringWageHour);check your stringWageHour it is definately have pairs of string which is giving u the position =0 and their value=12 like that